# RemoteViews method names

Tags: android, reflection, remoteview, method-names

I am creating an App which uses some widgets and I use `setInt()` method on a remoteView for changing the background source. That´s not a problem, but I wonder where the documentation about the method names is. In the RemoteViews API it is not documented which method names are valid and can be used. I read many articles about this, but everyone just saying, not all methods are available. But how can I know which method is supported? Is there any further link or description or a list for RemoteViews which method name I can use?

It´s the same with all the other methods from RemoteView like `setBoolean()` , `setDouble()` and so on. I also looked into Reflections of Android, but even here it is not documented.

All the questions here in stackoverflow that seems similar just handling one certain problem, but there is no answer about all the usable methods (or I really really must be blind).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for:

[android.view.RemotableViewMethod](http://grepcode.com/search/usages?id=repository.grepcode.com%24java%24ext@com.google.android%24android@4.1.1_r1@android%24view@RemotableViewMethod&type=type&k=u)

Comment: interesting....had not found that. I don´t know if this is what I want, there is no explanation. i think I will test the behaviour, if it´s realy what I want, I will vote up!